# Who wins in Texas hold 'em when the board has the best hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Scenarios that spring to mind are

1. **The board has a Hearts royal flush**: Nobody else has anything except one player has a 9 of hearts. Do they win because they have a straight flush?
2. **The board has a pair**: Nobody else has anything, do we just see who has the highest card?

Answer (score 0):

Poker hands have EXACTLY FIVE CARDS, no more, no less. If there's a royal on board, the best 5-card hand anyone can make is the royal, so the pot is split. (Same with any A-high straight on board, or quads with an A).

If the board is one pair, it depends: if it's A-A-K-Q-J, and no player has a second pair or any card higher than a 10, the the pot is split.  If it's A-A-9-7-5, and One player has K-3, he defeats a player with Q-10, because A-A-K-9-7 is higher than A-A-Q-10-9. But he would not defeat a player with K-2, because neither the 3 nor deuce play in the first five cards.

Comment: The 'quads with an A' is not correct I think. The 5th card matters, so the board can have a lower 5th card than one of the players is holding.

Comment: "Quads with an A", as in 4-4-4-4-A. Five cards.